# Why does clients reading my video via http.ServeContent keep closing the connection?

Tags: go, video-streaming

I am currently working on a small project for serving video to a browser or other media clients via http.ServeContent. I have implemented my own ReadSeeker which looks like this:

```
//the seek is not fully working yet but works fine for the initial two calls that is being called internally from http to decide the file size.

func (c *Client) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (t int64, e error) {
    switch whence {
    case 0:
        t = offset
    case 1:
        t = c.seek + offset
    case 2:
        t = c.SelectedFile().Length + offset
    }

    if c.seek != t {
        //TODO
        c.seek = t
    }

    return
}

func (c *Client) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if c.done {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }

    for {
        result := <-c.Results

        if result.piece == nil {
            return 0, io.EOF
        }

        for i, b := range result.bytes {
            index := int64(i)
            if index < 0 || index > c.SelectedFile().Length {
                continue
            }

            n++
            p[index] = b
        }

        return
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and dandy if I for instance use curl to fetch the data eg data keeps being streamed (1024 bytes per read). However as soon as I use a browser or even VLC, after between 5 to 10 reads the http writer.Write() returns an EPIPE error and the connection is broken. The error appear to come directly from dst.Write(buf[0:nr]) inside io.go :

```
...
func copyBuffer(dst Writer, src Reader, buf []byte) (written int64, err error) {
    ...
    for {
        nr, er := src.Read(buf)
        if nr > 0 {
            nw, ew := dst.Write(buf[0:nr])
            if nw > 0 {
                written += int64(nw)
            }
            if ew != nil {
                err = ew
                break
            }
            if nr != nw {
                err = ErrShortWrite
                break
            }
        }
        if er != nil {
            if er != EOF {
                err = er
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return written, err
}
```

I have tried to debug for days now and can't seem to figure out the cause.  I've been comparing the bytes I serve with the actual file and it does not not seem to be anything wrong with the data.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: If you use a http connection, the data must be send in the base 7 format. The client side must then convert it back to base 8.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. There is nothing that requires the client to not disconnect until the server has sent all the data. It is very common, especially for mp4 files, for the client to perform a standard http request, then cancel after it has received the headers.

I suspect however the video is not playing they way you expect? If that is the case, make sure your server  implements http range requests.

Comment: Oh the video is not playing at all, on any browser sorry for not mentioning that. The player loads but the connection is broken before it plays anything. Also the disconnects happen after just a couple of seconds, i have never experienced similar behaviour when streaming files before, so i am quite certain something is wrong with my implementation or the way i serve data. The range request should be handled properly when using http.ServeContent with a ReadSeeker according to the documentation.

Comment: `Also the disconnects happen after just a couple of seconds, i have never experienced similar behavior when streaming files before` Thats strange, because it very common, especial on apple clients. Only the option is you are corrupting the data somehow.

Comment: What do you mean its very common? So normally any attempt to see any video over http fails for you? Surely VLC which has an option to add a video steam wouldn't behave the same way as my browser? I get the exact same error after around the same amount of chunks. Maybe i should try to change to another OS to see if the issue persists but i do think something is wrong elsewhere

Comment: No, The client canceling an HTTP request (by closing the TCP session) before the last byte is received is very common.